# how can I save a compressed JPEG from an ALAsset

Tags: ios

I have an object ALAsset retrieved from ALAssetLibrary I want to extrapolate a compress JPEG in order to send it to a web services.

any suggestion where to start?

Edit:
I've found a way to get NSData out of the ALAsset

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rappresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rappresentation.size);
NSUInteger buffered = [rappresentation getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rappresentation.size error:&err];
```

but I can't find a way to reduce the size of the image by resizing and compressing it.
My idea was to have something like:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
//resize image
NSData *compressedData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 0.5);
```

but, first of all, even without resizing, just using this two lines of code compressedData is bigger than data. 
and second I'm not sure about what's the best way to resize the UIImage

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
[theAsset thumbnail]
```

Or;

Compressing might result bigger files after some point, you need to resize the image:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)cgImage scale:(CGFloat)scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get the CGImage from an `ALAssetRepresentation`:

```
ALAssetRepresentation repr = [asset defaultRepresentation];
// use the asset representation's orientation and scale in order to set the UIImage
// up correctly
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[repr fullResolutionImage] scale:[repr scale] orientation:[repr orientation]];
// then do whatever you want with the UIImage instance
```